# Config for all systemd services

Tags: reboot, systemd, systemctl

I would like to add a few config options either as defaults or overrides (preferrably the latter) to all systemd services on a system. Is that possible?

Background:
I have a server where sometimes services fail to start at boot due to hardware issues.
Rather than configuring `Restart=on-failure` for each service, I would like to somehow add it for all services.

Comment: I recommend you do not. Instead, change just the services where you know this is okay.

Comment: I will add an appropriate delay and burst limit, I really don't see how there could be a service where it is not okay. Besides, this is just context - this feature could be useful for configuring other things as well.